python и PyPy скрипт запущенный через cd\path python script.py не видит библиотеки
Я хочу запустить скрипт через команды
cd path 
python script.py

На этом моменте он не может импортировать библиотеки.
Работают методы:
1)
cd path
C:\Users\%username%\%Python%\Scripts\python.exe script.py

Или
2)
python Path\script.py.

Я вообще хочу использовать
pypy3.exe script.py

Но в этом случае путь к интерпретатору как в методе 1 прописать не могу..... Не очень понимаю как правильно в этом случае поступить....
Также я пробовал прописать
1)
cd Path
set PYTHONPATH=C:\path\to\package
python script.py

Тогда выдает ошибку:
import required dependencies:
numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from ther

Хотя numpy вообще в скрипте не используется, ошибка на импорте pandas.
2) Еще я пробовал использовать виртуально окружение, установил библиотеки, но он также не смог импортировать
Предположения:

Когда я пишу where python У меня высвечиваются 2 пути - соответственно у меня 2 интерпретатора, может быть нужно установить пакеты в оба, чтобы работало какой бы он по умолчанию не использовал? как тогда установить пакеты во второй путь?
Может быть он просто не может в данном каталоге найти библиотеки? поэтому спасает pythonpath, но тогда я не понимаю откуда возникает конфликт numpy.... может быть нужно перенести скрипт в другой каталог

PS Уже после вопроса, я заметил что в папке PYPY через который я пытаюсь запустить скрипт есть собственный python.exe, Может быть пакеты нужно установить и к этому интерпретатору? Это возможно и объясняет конфликт с пакетами другого интерпретатора, если я вручную PYTHOPATH прописываю.....

Какие библиотеки - вы имеете в виду модули в папке со скриптом или установленные через pip? Вы их установили глобально или в виртуальное окружение?

%project_folder%\Scripts\python.exe - у вас действительно python в папку проекта установлен, или вы имеете в виду здесь папку python?

ошибка на import pandas. pandas установлен глобально, если я пропишу python path/script.py он сможет импортировать. Также когда я пытался запустить в виртуальном окружении я установил и туда.... но результат не поменялся

Скорректировал вопрос, спасибо

С виртуальным окружением сложно, его нужно активировать, потом из него запускать, просто запуск через интерпретатор из окружения может не сработать. У меня сейчас все личные проекты на poetry, там проще - cd в папку проекта, и там делать poetry run python ..., запустится в виртуальном окружении проекта.

Venv я активировал, вообще здесь все по инструкции делал... мне кажется проблема в собственном интерпретаторе pypy (я просто вообще в нем не разбираюсь).....

Про pypy не могу ничего сказать, практически с ним не работал. Там вообще какие-то сложности были с библиотеками типа numpy, насколько я помню, но может за прошедшие годы что-то решили. Попробуйте погуглить pypy numpy

Да, предположение, что к PyPy нужно относиться как к самостоятельному интерпретатору - верное.
Установить именно pandas у PyPy так и не вышло, но другие пакеты - numpy, например, поставить можно (тут с pandas, как я понял, глобальные проблемы, не только у меня).
Здесь я сохраню инструкцию, которая помогла лично мне, она необязательно правильная, поэтому прошу строго не судить, а исправить, если найдете ошибки.
Инструкции будет две - для Windows и Ubuntu, т.к., чтобы установить пакеты  в PyPy, мне пришлось установить C++ Compiler.
Для Ubuntu:
На ubuntu легче -
$ sudo apt install g++
$ sudo apt install pypy3

Переходим в папку PyPy (возможно, это необязательно, но я делаю отсюда), и сначала устанавливаем pip для pypy:
# Download get-pip.py script
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

# Install pip using PyPy3
$ pypy3 get-pip.py

# Install numpy first
$ pypy3 -m pip install numpy

# Install pandas
$ pypy3 -m pip install pandas

На этом этапе у меня установился numpy, а pandas - failed building wheel.
Если кто-нибудь знает, как это решить, пожалуйста напишите!
Для Windows:
На винде c++ compiler устанавливается через MSYS2:

Перейдите на официальный сайт MSYS2 и скачайте установщик.
Запустите скачанный установщик и следуйте инструкциям на экране, чтобы установить MSYS2.

Далее переходим в нашу папку PyPy (возможно, это необязательно, но я делаю отсюда), и выполняем команды:
# Check PyPy3 installation
pypy3 --version

# Install pip using ensurepip (if not already installed)
pypy3 -m ensurepip

# Upgrade pip to the latest version (optional)
pypy3 -m pip install --upgrade pip


# Install
pypy3 -m pip install numpy
pypy3 -m pip install pandas

На этом этапе, возможно, будет ошибка pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
Она должна уйти, если установить C++ Compiler.
После установки необходимых пакетов запускайте скрипты через:
pypy3 script.py

или
pypy3.exe script.py

